# Show that the function $f(x)g(x)$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $A:=[a,b].$ Suppose that the function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous,  $g: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $g(x) \geq 0$ for almost all $x \in A.$

$(a)$ Show that the function $f(x)g(x)$ is integrable.

**My questions are:**

1-I know that the product of 2 Riemann integrable functions is again a Riemann integrable function by this question here [The product of two Riemann integrable functions is integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/the-product-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions-is-integrable) but the product of 2 Lebesgue integrable functions is not necessarily Lebesgue integrable (am I correct ?). What is the theorem that gives us the necessary conditions for the product of 2 Lebesgue integrable functions to be integrable?

2- I studied from " Real Analysis " by Royden and Fitzpatrick, fourth edition. But still, I do not know how to prove the above question, so could anyone help me in proving it, please?

Comment: You can approximate a continuous function to within $\varepsilon$ by a sum of characteristic functions and then use the integrability of $g$.

Comment: If a function is Riemann integrable then it is definitely Lebesgue Integrable.

Comment: @Integrand could you please write the details of your idea in an answer? and tell me if you agree with the answer given below or we must approximate? and if we must approximate, why we must do this?  .... thanks in advance

Comment: @lebesgue I do not see how your comment answers my questions above .... could you please explain more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, we have $|f(x)| \leqslant M$ and $|f(x) g(x)| \leqslant Mg(x)$ a.e..

You should be able now to conclude that $fg$ is integrable. See Proposition 16 (the Integral Comparison Test) in Royden.

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: The functions $f(x) = g(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ are Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1]$, but $f(x)g(x) =1/x$ is not.  So to answer "am I correct" -- yes you are.  As to when is the product integrable -- that is a broad question. I know of no concise set of necessary and sufficient conditions if that is what you want.  A more general sufficient condition is if $f$ is bounded and $g$ is integrable.  The same proof used above shows that $fg$ is integrable.

Comment: So what about approximating the function $f$ ..... do we need to do this?

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question .... why the function $1/x$ is not Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Are you referring to the suggestion to approximate the continuous function $f$ with simple functions? That is somewhat of an overkill.

Comment: Yes exactly I am referring to this.

Comment: @Smart20:  What is your understanding of what it means for a function to be Lebesgue integrable? I'm trying to see where you are having trouble here.  Are you comfortable with if $g$ is integrable, then so is $Mg$ where $M$ is a constant.?

Comment: Yes I am comfortable with this

Comment: the proof not yet.

Comment: Read this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2961197/148510).  It summarizes the approach to defining the Lebesgue integral that Royden uses. Then you will see why $|fg| \leqslant Mg$ implies that $fg$ is integrable. If $h$ is any bounded measurable function on $[a,b]$ such that $h \leqslant |fg|$ then since $Mg$ is integrable we have $\int_{[a,b]} h \leqslant M \int_{[a,b]} g$.  Thus $ \int_{[a,b]} |fg|  := \sup_{h}\int_{[a,b]}h < \infty$.

Comment: So $|fg|$ integrable implies $fg$ integrable. Finally you must know that $\int_0^1 x^{-1} \, dx = \infty$ As an improper integral and Lebesgue integral.

Comment: The key part here seems to be (I am no expert in Lebesgue stuff) that the integral needs to be a finite real number and thus bounded. If $f$ is unbounded then there is no guarantee that integral of $fg$ will remain bounded.